# Django MPESA integration with C2B Till Number Payment and STK Push

Tags: python, django, api, mpesa

I would like to be able to integrate MPESA API C2B Till Number Payment capabilities with STK push into a Django Web app I am working on such that the user of the platform gets an STK Push notification to pay to the till number and the transaction is stored in the database through a model.

I have seen some frameworks people have developed online but most seem to cater for paybill and not till. any help with frameworks that can help me do this will be appreciated.

I am finding the official documentation bulky and kind of difficult to work with from django.

Answer (score 2):

There is no huge difference between Paybill number and Till number. According to Safaricom documentation, for C2B [Safaricom C2B API](https://developer.safaricom.co.ke/c2b/apis/post/simulate) The command ID for paybill shortcode is **CustomerPayBillOnline** and for Buy Good and services is **CustomerBuyGoodsOnline**

With that said you can do something like this in Django for STK push:

```
def lipa_na_mpesa_online(request):
    access_token = MpesaAccessToken.validated_mpesa_access_token
    api_url = "https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/stkpush/v1/processrequest"
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % access_token}
    request = {
        "BusinessShortCode": LipanaMpesaPpassword.Business_short_code,
        "Password": LipanaMpesaPpassword.decode_password,
        "Timestamp": LipanaMpesaPpassword.lipa_time,
        "TransactionType": "CustomerBuyGoodsOnline",
        "Amount": 1,
        "PartyA": 254708374149,  # replace with your phone number to get stk push
        "PartyB": LipanaMpesaPpassword.Business_short_code,
        "PhoneNumber": 254708374149,  # replace with your phone number to get stk push
        "CallBackURL": "https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/",
        "AccountReference": "Henry",
        "TransactionDesc": "Testing stk push"
     }

     response = requests.post(api_url, json=request, headers=headers)
     return HttpResponse('success')
```

Comment: did you finish up the tutorial series after encountering the error on tutorial 5? I kinda am giving upon STK push cause I just realised it locks out android <4 users.

Comment: Yes I did a tutorial for Paybill, have a look at the following it will give you an insight. [Python/Django Mpesa API Integration](https://github.com/HenryLab/Python-Django-Mpesa-API-Integration)